# Re-apply for UK tier 4 student visa

Tags: student-visa, uk-visa, refusal

I applied for a UK Tier 4 General Student visa. My bank statement had my name handwritten in English and not printed, as my bank had to write it down and stamp twice, since my information on the bank system is only accepted in my country's language, which is not English. They said this is the right way to certify it since applying for a bank statement with my name printed in English was going to take time due to system routines and approvals. I applied for an English printed name version anyway, but it came out after my appointment so I had to use the bank statement with my name hand written on it.

Surprisingly, I received a refusal because my name is handwritten and not printed as the rest of the statement is.

Briefly, the Clearance Officer states:

> ... however, the name on the bank statement has been handwritten. This leads me to question if the bank statement is truly owned by you.
>
> UKVI has attempted to verify your bank statement and we have been unable to verify that this account is genuine. In accordance with paragraph 39B (c) of the Immigration Rules as we have been unable to verify your offer of financial circumstances, it has been discounted for the purpose of assessing your application.
>
> I am therefore not satisfied that you have achieved 10 points under paragraphs 10 to 14 of Appendix C and do not meet the requirements to be granted entry clearance under Tier 4 (General) Student). I therefore refuse your application under paragraph 245ZV (c) of the Immigration Rules.

I was advised to re-apply since I have fixed the problem.

Would I still be refused since my bank statement (with printed name in English) was issued before the refusal date, or there is no relation/no rule for that?

Please note that bank statement date had not passed 30 days of my new visa application and the required amount didn't drop for more than 28 days. I have no time to apply for a new bank statement and my course is starting within two weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Getting an important new document that addresses the refusal reason is a good basis for making a new application.

Can't be sure you will get your visa though. Once you show a verified statement, the visa office will make a decision on all of the information available and you may be refused on some other issue.